# PLSQL Code Function not returning Value

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am using function as

```
create or replace FUNCTION FSS_REF_GETREFIDBYCODEANDORDER (v_Code In CHAR, v_OrderBy In number )
RETURN number IS v_RefID NUMBER(10);

BEGIN

 SELECT REFID
 INTO v_RefID
 FROM REFERENCE
 WHERE Code like (v_Code || '%')
 AND
 ORDERBY = v_OrderBy
 and ROWNUM = 1;

 RETURN (v_RefID); 
 END;
```

It should return a Value because if I run it separately without function given below its giving the result as 1 desired 1 value

```
 SELECT REFID
 -- INTO v_RefID
 FROM REFERENCE
 WHERE Code like ('001' || '%')
 AND
 ORDERBY = 4
 and ROWNUM = 1;
```

Can anybody please help me out with any error in function. As I am new in PL/SQL programming.

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: "It should return a Value" What does it do instead? Do you get an error message?

Comment: I assume that the problem has to do with your use of the `char` datatype instead of using `varchar2`. Yet, without any hint on how you call function nor if you get an error message, this is impossible to tell.

Comment: @PeterLang -- I am simply creating this function in Sql developer and Compiling it.. It compile successfully but when I play/run the function it is returning me below output

ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "PSBD.FSS_REF_GETREFIDBYCODEANDORDER", line 7

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge I know that my concern it should return a value. But its giving me no value with output.

ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "PSBD.FSS_REF_GETREFIDBYCODEANDORDER", line 7

Comment: try this: `select FSS_REF_GETREFIDBYCODEANDORDER('001',4) from dual;` just to make sure you call it with the desired parameters

Answer (score 1):

Try changing "v_Code In CHAR" to "v_Code In VARCHAR2".
I would also recommend that you add NO_DATA_FOUND exception handler. E.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fss_ref_getrefidbycodeandorder(v_code IN VARCHAR2, v_orderby IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
  v_refid NUMBER(10);

BEGIN

  SELECT refid
    INTO v_refid
    FROM reference
   WHERE code LIKE (v_code || '%')
     AND orderby = v_orderby
     AND rownum = 1;

  RETURN(v_refid);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN no_data_found THEN
    RETURN NULL;
END;
```